# How to append new row kartik gridview in Yii2 and save data to database?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I'm new one in Yii2 and I am studying by myself about Yii2. I want to append new row in kartik gridview of Yii2-advanced template. I have tried to research many times on Google. Until now I'm stuck.

My question is that "Is it possible in Yii2 to implement this function with Yii2-extensions/plugins?". If it is possible, how to do?

Thank you in advanced. :)

Comment: HI please reade [mcve] and add your code or what you've tried please.

Comment: not clear what you are asking are you trying to create an `Add Row` kind of functionality, that adds some set of inputs dynamically by clicking the button and those inputs include `kartik/select2` ?

Comment: Let me say sorry for telling you not clear. I would like to do like this link:
https://www.google.com/search?q=dynamic+row+php&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiitsTXkKThAhXKMo8KHZX5CT4Q_AUIDygC&biw=1440&bih=725#imgrc=IXSYDoLdphicvM:

Comment: take a look to pjax, https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-pjax google it if you don't know what is it.